# Public Static Void Add(Ship) is not working. Don't know how to "add ship"

Tags: c#, class, addition

I am working on my project and am having problems with a couple lines of code. I'm brand new to C# so I don't really understand it as much as I would like to yet. I was asked to create a new class called "Ships" that will allows you to add a ship {void Add(Ship)} and reset the collection {void Clear()}. This is what I've come up with but again, there are problems I don't know how to fix. Thank you for the help.

. Lines 44 through 59 don't seem to be working. 
. I am trying to enter a void Add(Ship) method that will allow you to add a ship
. The add method should validate that no ships are overlapping
. If there is a collision this method should throw a suitable exception

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Module_4_Battleship
  {

    public class Ships 
    {
        public string ShipName { get; set; }
        public ShipOrientation Orientation { get; set; }
        public int ShipNum { get; set; }
        public int ExtentUnits { get; set; }
        public int Position_Row { get; set; }
        public int Position_Col { get; set; }
        static bool PlayerGameOver, GameOverBool;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Ship Number: " + ShipNum + "   Ship Name: " + ShipName;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            Ship objAsShip = obj as Ship;
            if (objAsShip == null) return false;
            else return Equals(objAsShip);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ShipNum;
        }
        public bool Equals(Ship other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.ShipNum.Equals(other.ShipNum));
        }

        ***public static void Add(Ship)
        {
            List<Ship> ships = new List<Ship>
            {
                new Ship() { ShipName = "Battleship", ShipNum = 1 },
                new Ship() { ShipName = "Cruiser", ShipNum = 2 },
                new Ship() { ShipName = "Submarine", ShipNum = 3 },
                new Ship() { ShipName = "Attacker", ShipNum = 4 },
                new Ship() { ShipName = "The Soldier", ShipNum = 5 },
                new Ship() { ShipName = "Boat", ShipNum = 6 }***
            };
            ;


            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (Ship aShip in ships)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aShip);
            }


            Console.WriteLine("\nContains(\"1\"): {0}",
            ships.Contains(new Ship { ShipNum = 1, ShipName = "" }));


            Console.WriteLine("\nInsert(2, \"2\")");
            ships.Insert(2, new Ship() { ShipName = "Cruiser", ShipNum = 2 
 });


            //Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (Ship aShip in ships)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aShip);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nParts[3]: {0}", ships[3]);

            Console.WriteLine("\nRemove(\"1534\")");


            ships.Remove(new Ship() { ShipNum = 3, ShipName = "Submarine" 
});

            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (Ship aShip in ships)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aShip);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nRemoveAt(3)");

            ships.RemoveAt(3);

            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (Ship aShip in ships)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aShip);
            }

        }
        public void clear()
        {

            Console.Clear();
        }

        public bool Attack(int Row, int Col)
        {
            if (this.Orientation == ShipOrientation.Horizontal)
                return (
                   Row == this.Position_Row
                   &&
                   Col >= Position_Col
                   &&
                   Col <= (Position_Col + ExtentUnits - 1)
                 );
            else
                return (
                   Col == this.Position_Col
                   &&
                   Row >= Position_Row
                   &&
                   Row <= (Position_Row + ExtentUnits - 1)
                 );
        }
        public enum ShipOrientation
        {
            Horizontal = 0,
            Vertical
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this class is only supposed to `Add()` a ship, and `Clear()` all ships, why do you have so much other stuff going on?  You only need a class that has a collection (public or private, you decide) of type `Ship` and two methods to `Add()` to that collection, and `Clear()` all items from that collection.  Your could is doing too much, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: The OP is just learning to walk - giving tips on how to run efficiently is probably a bit much at this point in time.

Comment: @serpent5 nothing I said is advanced C# or programming in general.  Its simply **following the directions**.  OP's confusion could very well be due to the code not following the principle of _keeping it simple_.

Comment: The error is due to `Add(Ship)` - this needs to have a parameter name e.g. `Add(Ship shipToAdd)`. You can then use `shipToAdd` inside the function just like `other` is used in the `Equals` function.

Comment: This was everything I was asked to do.... Ships should have the following properties:
• A way to store a collection of the Ship class from last week.

• void Add(Ship) 
          
• void Clear()
          
• bool SunkMyBattleship {get; private set}
           - This readonly property returns true if the battleship has been sunk.
          .
• bool Attack(int x, int y)
         -This is the method that attacks the collection of ships and marks any 
          positions as hit.

Comment: @F.C That changes things, you did not indicate that there was more to the assignment in your question.  serpent5's latest comment is why your code wont compile

Comment: To me it looks like you are mixing up two classes here that should be separate. You should have a Ship class that contains a ship's properties like orientation etc and then have Ships class that contains a collection of Ship instances

Comment: I'm sorry, I honestly didn't think I needed to include all the information. But thank you for the help, what you suggested worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Some of this has already been pointed out in the comments, but here it goes.

As indicated in the comments, this class seems to conflate the concept of a ship and the concept of a *collection* of ships. I strongly suggest splitting them.

Secondly, the signature of the `Add` method is incorrect:

```
public static void Add(Ship)
```

`Ship` is the type/class name, but (as also pointed out in the comments) you also need to include a variable name if you're trying to add a specific ship.

Also, the `clear` method is incorrect. All this does is clear the console - it doesn't actually do anything to the underlying data:

```
public void clear()
{
    Console.Clear();
}
```

Also, it looks like your `Add` method does a lot of stuff other than just adding a ship to the collection. As a professor of mine used to say, you generally shouldn't have to use the word "and" when describing what a method or class does.

On a related note, I actually *strongly* recommend using C#'s [XML Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments) feature to describe the purpose of each of your methods, especially since you're still new to the language. Basically, this enables you to write a summary, description of your arguments, description of your return value, describe what exceptions it may throw, etc. - Visual Studio will even use it to generate Intellisense. You can put as much detail as you want, or just write some basic details (e.g. a summary of the method). Trust me, it helps, and the more thorough you are the more it helps. For example, awhile back I was having trouble writing a method, so I tried to write XML documentation for it; I quickly realized that I couldn't remember why I was adding the method in the first place (hence the reason I was having trouble writing it). It's definitely helped me get "unstuck" and/or debug quite a few times, too.

One final code issue: right now you just store the data locally to the `Add` method. That means that, as soon as the `Add` method finishes, your list of ships (along with any changes you made to it) will be lost.